# How to disable copilot popping up new tab in split

Tags: github-copilot

I just started using copilot in vscode. I found the suggestion quite useful. However, every now and then it pop up a new tab in the split windows on my right. And started generating 10 suggestion. I found that to be quite interrupting. Is there any method to disable this one without disabling the inline suggestion?

Also would that be possible to have a hot key to toggle / trigger such behaviour?

Thanks